# Same day of Last Week and Last Month PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need date functions as below.

Last month of a specific date selected and the same day last week.

Example
4th day of last week = today 2020-12-02 return 2020-11-25

same day last month = today 2020-12-02 return 2020-11-04

Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same week day last week it's easy. Since the DATE is kept as an integer representing the days elapsed since the 12/30/1899, it's enough to subtract 7 from the current date.

```
Same Week Day Last Week = 
VAR CurrentDay = MAX('Date'[Date])
RETURN CurrentDay - 7
```

The same week day last month measure is lacking a precise definition.

It's not possible to map weeks over months and for this reason week based calendars exist.

Here is a DAX measure that tries to keep most of the days inside the month

```
Same Week Day last month = 
VAR CurrentDay =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR WeekDaysDelta =
    WEEKDAY ( EOMONTH ( CurrentDay, -1 ) ) - WEEKDAY ( EOMONTH ( CurrentDay, -2 ) )
VAR DaysAdjust =
    IF (
        WeekDaysDelta > 3,
        WeekDaysDelta - 7,
        IF ( WeekDaysDelta < -3, WeekDaysDelta + 7, WeekDaysDelta )
    )
VAR SameWeekDay =
    EOMONTH ( CurrentDay, -2 ) + DAY ( CurrentDay ) + DaysAdjust
RETURN
    SameWeekDay
```

There is an [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard that defines week based calendars.

Here is a link to an article about working with weeks in DAX

[Week-related calculations](https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/)